# Find constants $0<x_i\leq y_i<\infty$ such that conditions hold

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n\geq 2$ and suppose $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$ are constants such that, for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, one has
$$
0<x_i < y_i<\infty.
$$

**Edit**

I would like to know if (and if yes: how) it is possible to choose the constants such that
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n y_j\leq\frac{y_i}{x_i}\leq\left(\prod_{j=1}^nx_j\right)^{-1}\qquad\textrm{for all }i=1,2,\ldots,n.\tag{1}
$$

I think it makes sense to start with $n=2$ and $n=3$.

For $n=2$, (1) holds if we choose
$$
x_2:=y_1^{-1},\quad y_2:=x_1^{-1}.
$$

However, already the case $n=3$ seems to be much more difficult.

For $n=3$, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y_1*y_2*y_3%20%3C%3D%20y_1%2Fx_1%20%3C%3D%201%2F%28x_1*x_2*x_3%29%2C%20y_1*y_2*y_3%20%3C%3D%20y_2%2Fx_2%20%3C%3D%201%2F%28x_1*x_2*x_3%29%2C%20y_1*y_2*y_3%20%3C%3D%20y_3%2Fx_3%20%3C%3D%201%2F%28x_1*x_2*x_3%29%2C%200%3Cx_1%3Cy_1%2C%200%3Cx_2%3Cy_2%2C%200%3Cx_3%3Cy_3) says that one possible solution is

$$
x_1>0,\quad x_2>0,\quad 0<x_3<\frac{1}{x_1 x_2},
$$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x_1}}{\sqrt{x_2}\sqrt{x_3}}\leq y_1<\frac{1}{x_2 x_3},
$$
$$
x_2<y_2\leq\frac{1}{x_3 y_1},
$$
$$
x_3 < y_3\leq \frac{1}{x_2 y_1}.
$$
I verified that this is indeed a solution.

Now, I am wondering if this solution can be generalized for $n>3$.

Comment: All constants equal to one is always a solution, isn't it?

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A special choice of constants would be to set $x_i=x$, $y_i=y$ for all $i$.

Then the desired conditions reduce to
$$
0<x<y\\
y^n\leq y/x\leq x^{-n}
$$
This can be reduced easily to
$$
y>0\\\begin{cases}0<x<y&y\leq 1\\0<x\leq y^{1-n}&y>1\end{cases}
$$